# How to know if a number is in a determinated interval in R

Tags: r, intervals, binning

I have a dataset with 3 columns: Default, Height and Weight.

I made a binning of the variables and almacenated it (I have to do it this way) in a list. Every binning has a woe associated, but now I want to put those woes in the original Dataframe depending in which buckets are my observations:
For example, the data frame

```
df1 <- data.frame(default=sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100, prob=c(0.9,0.1)),
                  height=sample(150:180, 100, replace=T),
                  weight=sample(50:80,100,replace=T))
> head(df1)
#    default  height  weight
# 1       0    172     54
# 2       0    169     71
# 3       0    164     61
# 4       0    156     55
# 5       0    180     66
# 6       0    162     63
```

The bins (I will just show the first one)

```
bins <- lapply(c("height","weight"), function(x) woe.binning(df1, "default", x,
                                                 min.perc.total=0.05,
                                                 min.perc.class=0.05,event.class=1,
                                                 stop.limit = 0.05)[2])
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
#                woe cutpoints.final cutpoints.final[-1] iv.total.final  0 1 col.perc.a col.perc.b      iv.bins
# (-Inf,156] -46.58742            -Inf                 156      0.1050725 21 5 0.24137931 0.38461538 0.0667299967
# (156,168]   23.91074             156                 168      0.1050725 34 4 0.39080460 0.30769231 0.0198727638
# (168,169]  -10.91993             168                 169      0.1050725  6 1 0.06896552 0.07692308 0.0008689599
# (169, Inf]  25.85255             169                 Inf      0.1050725 26 3 0.29885057 0.23076923 0.0176007627
# Missing           NA             Inf             Missing      0.1050725  0 0 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

Now I want to see in with bins is my data. 
My desired output is something similar to this

```
#    default  height  weight woe_height   woe_weight
# 1       0    160     54      23.91074   -8.180032
# 2       0    140     71     -46.58742   -7.640947
```

Is there any way to do it? The main problem I see here is that the intervals (a,b) are `strings`. I was thinking about use `substr()` or something similar to separate the strings in logical options, but I dont think that would work, and its not very elegant.
Any help will be welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work fine for you?

```
apply_woe_binning <- function(df, x){

  # woe binning
  w <- woe.binning(df, "default", x,
                   min.perc.total=0.05,
                   min.perc.class=0.05,
                   event.class=1,
                   stop.limit = 0.05)[[2]]

  # create new column name
  new_col <- paste("woe", x, sep = "_")

  # define cuts
  cuts <- cut(df[[x]], w$cutpoints.final)

  # add new column
  df[[new_col]] <- w[cuts, "woe", drop = TRUE]

  df
}

# one by one
df2 <- apply_woe_binning(df1, "height")
df2 <- apply_woe_binning(df2, "weight")


# in a functional
df2 <- Reduce(function(y, x) apply_woe_binning(df = y, x = x), 
              c("height","weight"),
              init = df1)
```